# Using Word wildcards, how to search for EITHER Figure or Fig

Tags: search, wildcard, cpu-word

I need to search for figure numbers and replace them. In the body of the text, it would be Fig. F.2-3 but in the caption it is Figure F.2-3. I can't figure out a wildcard expression that covers both!

Thanks

Comment: Pretty simple, really. Find = <Fig[ure.]@{1,3}

Comment: Oh, nice. I had worked out that Figure F.3-5 and Fig. F.3-5 could be represented as [rg][e.], ignoring the Fi before. That was working, but I like yours because I had never used the "beginning of the expression" operator. Thanks!